# Getting backslash-unescaped characters

Tags: php, regex, string, filter, backslash

I am working on a date conversion function like date() and need to parse string and leave escaped characters.

I mean changing $str1 to $str2 by regular expression (or any better way):

```
$str1 = '5852& ^ \a\\b\\\\\c D \\e k.';
$str2 = 'bDek';
```

$str2 has only [a-zA-Z] which are not escaped by backslashes.

Regards,

Comment: @fge not in perl in php man! I got it in JavaScript too!

Comment: @micha the regex I put out is compatible with PCRE (hence PHP) _and_ ECMA 262 (hence JavaScript)...

Comment: @fge how can you know that have you tested it?

Comment: @micha I know it because I know what constructs can be used with both of these regex dialects... Both support non capturing groups and word anchors which are the only two "non legacy" constructs that I'm using here.

Answer (score 0):

This may solve that for you:

```
(?:^|[^\\](?:\\\\)*)([a-zA-Z])\b
```

Perl demo:

```
$ perl -ne 'print "-->$_<--\n" foreach m/(?:^|[^\\](?:\\\\)*)([a-zA-Z])\b/g'
5852& ^ \a\\b\\\\\c D \\e k.                                                                              
-->b<--
-->D<--
-->e<--
-->k<--
o\a\\b\\\c\\\\d
-->o<--
-->b<--
-->d<--
```

The regex reads:

```
(?:               # begin non capturing group
  ^               # the beginning of input,
  |               # or
  [^\\]           # a character which is not a backslash, followed by
  (?:\\\\)*       # two backslashes, zero or more times
)                 # end non capturing group, followed by
([a-zA-Z])        # a letter, captured, followed by
\b                # a word break
```

Comment: Thanks @fge. How can i use it in PHP? `"/(?:^|[^\\](?:\\\\)*)([a-zA-Z])\b/"` as preg_replace() pattern doesn't work!

Comment: I guess your best bet here is to use `preg_match_all` instead and collect the result into an array. It is then a matter of building the result string by concatenating the array elements into a string... I'm sure PHP has something like that in store (note: I don't know PHP save for the regex-related functions)